# Docker fails during aws cdk deploy with syntax error in pattern

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Building a pipeline with aws cdk and although is building locally i get this error while running inside the aws container.

[image]
[image]

Comment: check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/51898744/3815522 - I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: thanks for the link, you are right i had docker ignore `bin\
obj\'

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @[user3815522](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3815522/user3815522) for the link

@[rosalindwills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811189/rosalindwills) for the solution

it was the `.dockerignore` file having windows style backslashes